# How to create cross platform xamarin library which uses phone's GPS module?

Tags: xamarin, gps, cross-platform, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am a beginning JS programmer developing in Angular but now I got assigned this task: create a library that accesses phone's GPS module, gyroscope and accelerometer (and possibly a compass) to gather acceleration, position and some other data. It's not a whole lot of code really.Now, creating the library itself in C# is already done by a colleague but I need to know if there' s a way to include objective-C and java code as well into the library which would be the platform specific code for ios/droid respectively. 
The result literally has to be a single dll file and it must be useable in xamarin. The requirement even was for the library to work with angular which I have no idea if is even possible. It would be a bonus if it could. 
What options do we have in accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a portable class library (PCL) that targets all platforms you want. In this PCL you'll have an interface that needs to be implemented in every platform, using platform specific code. Say:

```
public interface IGps
{
    int SomeFunc();
}
```

Every code that manipulates the GPS info will do so in the PCL using this interface.

In each platform you want to target, you'll need a class that implements this interface and injects it into the PCL using a Dependency Injection framework. This way you'll be using platform specific from the PCL without it knowing the implementation details for each platform.

```
public class GPSWindowsPhone : IGPS
{
    public int SomeFunc() 
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

As for using each platform's native code, it can be done using bindings for [Obj-C](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/) and [Java](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/) code and then using the class that implements the interface as a simple wrapper for the code written in the native language. However, if you still haven't done any platform specific coding I'd recommend writing them in C# already.

Regarding Angular, you can look at some [language] to JS compilers, but I'd just rewrite it :P

Comment: Thank you, hopefully I'll be able to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

There are already a number of Cross Platform Libraries in the Component store.

Xlabs has one
https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Geolocator
Gives you Lat,Long and Heading in an event driven model you can then use to get speed direction acceleration etc. Works in Xamarin on IOS Android and WP.